# How to set up Pydevd remote debugging with Heroku

Tags: heroku, pydev, pycharm

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6989965/how-do-i-start-up-remote-debugging-with-pycharm) I am required to copy the pycharm-debug.egg file to my server, how do I accomplish this with a Heroku app so that I can remotely debug it using Pycharm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku **doesn't expose the File system** it uses for running web dyno to users. Means you can't copy the file to the server via ssh.

So, you can do this by following 2 ways:

1. The best possible way to do this, is by **adding this egg file into requirements**, so that during deployment it gets installed into the environment hence automatically added to python path. But this would require the package to be pip indexed
2. Or, Commit this **file in your code base**, hence when you deploy the file reaches the server.
   Also, in the settings file of your project if using django , **add** this file to **python path**:

> ```
> import sys
> sys.path.append(relative/path/to/file)
> ```

Comment: How do you add the egg file into the requirements?