# PyCharm Remote option is not available

Tags: pycharm, remote-debugging

I'm trying to set up remote deploy with Raspberry Pi and PyCharm. Unfortunatelly  it seems that there is no such option under settings. How can I solve it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the community edition of pycharm. Professional Edition  has the add remote feature.

Answer (score 0):

You need to [configure](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/987276/Remote-Programming-of-RaspberryPi-using-PyCharm) first the PyCharm. But always have the [roots way](http://blog.gocept.com/2013/07/31/reproducable-automated-deployments-on-raspberrypi-with-batou/) using only CLI.

**adding some news:**
If you are using Windows, maybe you need to do some [extra configs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7061956/2983483).