# Received "/: Event not found." when using PyCharm remote dubugger

Tags: python, ssh, pycharm, remote-debugging, tcsh

When I use PyCharm with remote debug through ssh to a **tcsh shell server**, many times its stops working, and displays "/: Event not found"

More specifically, I encounter the following in pycharm debug console.

`ssh://username@hostserver:22/path/to/bin/python -u /path/to/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/pydevd.py --cmd-line --multiproc --qt-support=auto --client '0.0.0.0' --port 40426 --file /path/to/python/file/main.py 
/: Event not found.`

Is the problem owing to **history substitution** in tcsh shell? Because I can get the same response when typing `!/`.

I find some similar questions like [Issue with pycharm remote debug (“/: Event not found.” )](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000106430-Issue-with-pycharm-remote-debug-Event-not-found-) and [Event not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40586031/how-to-debug-remote-python-script), but no useful answer.

Sometimes this problem disappears automatically, which is weird.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having similar issue.

I have fixed this by removing `remote_source` file from `~/Library/Caches/PyCharm20017.3` directory.

Please note that I'm using macOS.

Comment: worked for me on macOS. any idea what's the path on Windows?

Comment: On Windows the path is: "C:\Users\MyUser\.PyCharm2019.1\system\remote_sources". Deleting this fixed the issue for me (what I don't understand is why this folder is so huge on Windows compared to mac)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and received an answer from JetBrains. It was caused by PyCharm not supporting csh, and the temporary solution is to use bash until PyCharm supports csh. After changing login shell to bash in Linux, the remote debugger started working.

Comment: I also think so... All is well after changing csh to bash.