# python tornado remote debugging via vagrant ERROR

Tags: python, windows, vagrant, pycharm, remote-debugging

I'm using win10 and I want to debug my project remotely using PyCharm. I believe I have configured it correctly, because my project starts as expected without debugging. However, when I try to debug it, I get these errors:

```
ssh://vagrant@127.0.0.1:2222/usr/bin/python -u /home/vagrant/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/pydevd.py --multiproc --qt-support --client '0.0.0.0' --port 36711 --file /vagrant/main.py start daemon
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vagrant/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 26, in <module>
    from _pydevd_bundle.pydevd_additional_thread_info import PyDBAdditionalThreadInfo
  File "/home/vagrant/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_additional_thread_info.py", line 19, in <module>
    from _pydevd_bundle.pydevd_additional_thread_info_regular import PyDBAdditionalThreadInfo  # @UnusedImport
  File "/home/vagrant/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_additional_thread_info_regular.py", line 5, in <module>
    from _pydevd_bundle.pydevd_frame import PyDBFrame
  File "/home/vagrant/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_frame.py", line 16, in <module>
    from _pydevd_bundle.pydevd_frame_utils import add_exception_to_frame, just_raised
ImportError: cannot import name add_exception_to_frame
```

Comment: From a first look it seems that your remote [project mappings](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/edit-project-path-mappings-dialog.html) are not quite right. If that doesn't solve your issue you may find [this thorough answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6989965/how-do-i-start-up-remote-debugging-with-pycharm) helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pycharm: File>Invalidate caches>Invalidate and Restart
Helped me.